# date between and get all possible values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'am using the following query to retrieve all possible values from a view for the whole month

```
     select * from report2 where date_from >= TO_DATE('01-July-2014 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY 
     HH24:MI:SS') AND date_from < TO_DATE('31-July-2014 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

I thought that's gonna detect all of them. But when I run for example the upper bound date to be 01-August-2014 I can still see entries from 31/July/2014 like 31/07/2014 00:01:00 which have not been retrieved by the previous query. How can I make sure that I will detect all of them??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using date till dawn of next month, when index over `date_from` is benefited.

```
 select * from report2 where 
     date_from >= TO_DATE('01-July-2014','DD-Month-YYYY')
 AND date_from < TO_DATE('01-August-2014','DD-Month-YYYY')
```

Or

`select * from report2 where TO_CHAR(date_from ,'MON-YYYY') = 'JUL-2014'`

if there's no index over `date_from`

Comment: Oh. I thought it also needs to be 00:00:00 to catch the very last minute? But your query works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use the `DATE` keyword in Oracle.  It makes such code much easier to read and uses ISO standard date formats:

```
select *
from report2
where date_from >= DATE '2014-07-01' and date_from < DATE '2014-08-01'
```

You might find it easier to follow the query as:

```
where date_from >= DATE '2014-07-01' and date_from < DATE '2014-07-31' + 1
```

or even:

```
where date_from >= DATE '2014-07-01' and date_from < add_months(DATE '2014-07-01', 1)
```